# What is the status of Elijah in Islam?

Tags: prophets

I heard somewhere that jews and some Christians too invoke Elijah in their prayers and feasts. He is considered to be the most important after Moses in Judaism. So what I wanted to know is if Elijah is mentioned in Quran and what his status is in Islam.

Answer (score 2):

Eliyah is called Eliyas (**إلياس**) in Arabic, he is a Messenger in Islam and is mentioned in the Quran as follows:

> وإن إلياس لمن المرسلين
>   إذ قال لقومه ألا تتقون
>   أتدعون بعلا وتذرون أحسن الخالقين
>   الله ربكم ورب آبائكم الأولين
>   فكذبوه فإنهم لمحضرون
>   إلا عباد الله المخلصين
>   وتركنا عليه في الآخرين
>   سلام على إل ياسين
>
> And indeed, Elias was from among the messengers
>   When he said to his people, "Will you not fear Allah ?
>   Do you call upon Ba'l and leave the best of creators -
>   Allah, your Lord and the Lord of your first forefathers?"
>   And they denied him, so indeed, they will be brought [for punishment],
>   Except the chosen servants of Allah .
>   And We left for him [favorable mention] among later generations:
>   "Peace upon Elias."
>
> <sup>— [Quran 37:123-130](https://legacy.quran.com/37/123-130)</sup>